# How can I have all the line in the diff using diff_match_patch?

Tags: python, diff

I'm using the Google [diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library for Python.

Suppose that I compare these two files (prepend 'Z' on line **2**)

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Zbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

The generated diff is :

```
@@ -50,16 +50,17 @@
 aaaaaaa%0A
+Z
 bbbbbbbb
```

The problem is that the diff doesn't contain all the line. **I would like something like that** :

```
@@ -50,16 +50,17 @@
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%0A
+Z
 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

How can I have all the line in the diff using diff_match_patch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/LineOrWordDiffs). Transcribing the JS example to Python results in the following output:

```
@@ -54,65 +54,66 @@
 aaa%0A
-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb%0A
+Zbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb%0A
 cccc
```

Which is still not ideal, but slightly better.

Comment: Yes. The diff_match_patch library already has this method. But it does not work well. Strange. After translating the code, it seems to be better :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using python's built in difflib
http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff

Comment: difflib has no method to make patches and to apply them in order to detect some conflicts between two files. I can't.

Comment: did you have a look at this python patch util? I think it can patch difflib diffs, but I haven't tried it myself. http://code.google.com/p/python-patch/

Comment: Yeah but there're no documentation :(